# zend, access app without loading controllers?

Tags: zend-framework

if i wanted to have my app load profile names, like this:  www.mydomain.com/simon    where simon isnt a controller, its the username of the user to bring up the profile, is this possible?

```
class ProfileController extends Zend_Controller_Action {


    public function init() {

    }

    public function indexAction(){

        echo $this->_request->getParam('profileuser');
```

this is where i can display the user.

```
    }
```

or something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `Zend_Route` for this purpose.

Just add the following to your application Bootstrap:

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $frontController->getRouter();

    $router->addRoute('profile', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':profileuser', 
        array('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'profile', 'action' => 'index')
    ));
}
```

More information on using `Zend_Controller_Router` [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html).

Comment: done. but i now get this error:Fatal error: Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: profileuser is not specified in C:\wamp\www\discoveredd2\library\Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\HelperAbstract.php on line 522

Answer (score 0):

Presuming `ProfileController` is your default Controller, so you will get there by default, you can use

```
$profileName = ltrim($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri(), "/");
```

in `indexAction` to get 'simon' from your url.